# Why is Array concatenation throwing an error in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, string, typescript, concatenation

I'm quite new to TypeScript. I was experimenting with classes and happened to see an error.

```
class DataStorage {
    private data:string[] = [];
    
    addItem(item: string){
        this.data.push(item);
    }

    removeItem(item: string){
        this.data.splice(this.data.indexOf(item), 1);
    }

    getItems(): string[]{
        return [...this.data];
    }

    // below code gives an error
    getConcatedItems(){
        const arr:string[] = [];
        return arr.concat[this.data];
    }
}
```

In the above code `this.data` present in  `getConcatedItems` is showing an error that says `Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type.`. While the `getItems` does not show any error.

Why would this happen and what could be a resolution for this?

Comment: Because it needs to be `arr.concat(this.data);`

Comment: You used square brackets to call a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just misspelling. Should be

```js
return arr.concat(this.data);
```

So round brackets instead of square ones.